# Integrating Thunderbird with Groupwise

Tags: thunderbird, groupwise

Is it possible to use Thunderbird to connect to a Groupwise server (i.e. from home to work). I want to be able to connect to the Groupwise server at work through my standard email client.

What settings do I need to enter in Thunderbird?

Answer (score 0):

It's really quite straightforward, at least if you have IMAP enabled in Groupwise:

1. Go to Account Settings -> Account Actions -> Add email account...
2. Hopefully you know your name and email address.
3. For server, use the name of your groupwise server. (Eg, gw.yourdomain.example) [It may also get autodetected as something like mail.yourdomain.example, although in my case that did not match the certificates.]
4. Choose an encryption option (any should work).
5. Profit. :)

Next steps, at least for me:

1. Figure out LDAP settings.
2. Find a way to liberate calendar data.

I probably should check with our Groupwise admins...